# Unexpected <qualifier name>

Tags: berkeley-db-xml

I am running the following command which is running perfectly in other XQuery processors

```
for $title in doc("dbxml:/auction/auction")/site/regions/* 
for $tit in $title for $it in $tit/item 
let $country:=$it/location 
group by $country 
return <result><loc>{ $country }</loc><num>{count($title)}</num></result>
```

However, in Berkeley I am getting an inexplicable error:

[image]

Please help.

P.S. Will provide more details if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Berkeley XML DB doesn't support group by of XQuery 3.0